# react js notifications sound with new audio

Tags: reactjs

Currently im trying to make a notification sound when user recive a notification on website this is my example:

```
  const notificationSound = () => {
    const audio = new Audio(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/notificationsound.mp3`);
    audio.load();
    audio.play().catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  };
```

and in my console im getting this:

```
DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.
```

Comment: The error stated that the user FIRST has to interact with the page before the audio plays. It is the same thing with videos.

Comment: I understand but here i dont have play button or something, this is for notifications so when user recive notification i called in useeffect this notificationSound()

Comment: You need to listen to mouse events. then trigger your actions.

Comment: But i already told u i dont have here mouse events, just checking notificationcount and when notificationcount > 0 i just play this sound. I also tryed something with audio.muted but didnt solve this.. Any ideas?

Comment: There has to be some sort of interaction [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Zqa.png), otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: Ok i will try this example..